# VBA - How to filter and copy the data from pivot table?

Tags: vba, excel

Good Day! Let say I have this Pivot table in my excel. From image below, I want to filter **BrandA** and copy all brand **BrandA** and paste it into new Sheet the same goes to **BrandX** and **BrandZ**.
[image]

Please help me :(

Thank you!

**EDITED 1**
Below is my recorded macro.

```
Sub MacroTest2()

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Brand")
    .PivotItems("BrandA").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("BrandZ").Visible = False
End With

Range("A4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Pivot").Select

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Brand").ClearAllFilters
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Brand")
    .PivotItems("BrandX").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("BrandZ").Visible = False
End With

Range("A4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Pivot").Select

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Brand").ClearAllFilters
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Brand")
    .PivotItems("BrandA").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("BrandX").Visible = False
End With

Range("A4:A5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Pivot").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What problems are you currently having?

Comment: Start the macro recorder. Set a filter in the pivot table. Copy the resulting pivot table. Paste into a new sheet. Stop the macro recorder. Look at the code and adjust it. Once you have code, we're happy to help adjust it. But we won't write it for you from scratch.

Comment: @YowE3K..Thanks for your time..To be honest I don't know how to do it. I'm still learning in programming esp. VBA.. Sorry sir :(

Comment: First, use `PivotFields("Brand")`, set the value of the `PivotItem` you want to filter. After, you can copy `PivotFields("Brand").PivotItem("BrandA").DataRange` or something similar - these 2 will get you started

Comment: @YowE3K.. Sir I've already recorded the macro. How am I going to make it dynamically?

Comment: @teylyn.. Sir I've already recorded the macro. How am I going to make it dynamically?

Comment: @jhovyn Ma'm, maybe you want to learn about some VBA programming basics before tackling such a complex topic? If you are not capable of controlling a tricycle you should not be given the tools to run an 18 wheeler truck. With all due respect, ma'm, but please get started with the basics first, so we can give you advice on the specifics.

Comment: @jhovyn Getting pivot data is really complex, but you can copy the worksheet values which is much simpler. Tell us what's not what's not working with the code you pasted and we'll go from there.

Comment: @teylyn..I know the basic of VBA programming but I'm not good as you that's why I'm seeking for any help..

Comment: @Absinthe..Since the code above is recorded macro, I dont have any problem encountered. The only thing that I'm asking is how am I going to make it dynamically since it's only a recorded macro, a static code perhaps..